# Add extra field in manytomany relationship in django

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I am try to create Model of my application but confused in the layout

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0,unique=True)

class Kit(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

Now a person can add multiple products in the app and a Kit can have multiple products,
the problem starts here.. I want to add quantity field to the `Kit` model such that a person can add a particular item and its quantity in a kit. How do I do that ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Extend your `Kit` model like so:

```
class Kit(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

Then the user can define the `Product` and its `quantity` within a `form`. That's all you need really to cover your presented setup.

**Update to your comment**

Then I would go for another relationship like so:

```
class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    # and remove it from the Kit Model
```

so every `Product` can be linked to its `quantity`

Comment: But I cannot have `quantity` of every `product` by this solution

Comment: @RahulSharma ah didn't get your issue straight from the start then. In this case I would add another relationship, see update in answer